# Finding and highlighting the characters not included in my list

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a VBA code, which finds and highlights the characters in the column, which are not specified by me in the code. The below code only finds the cell if it contain the character other than that mentioned in the code, but does not highlight that specific character. Can any one help me to highlight that specific character not listed in code

```
Sub ReplChars()
Dim sCharOK As String, s As String
Dim r As Range, rc As Range
Dim j As Long

sCharOK = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789,-.:;{}[]_"

Set r = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)

' loop through all the cells with text constant values and paints in yellow the ones with characters not in sCharOK
For Each rc In r
    s = rc.Value
    For j = 1 To Len(s)
        If InStr(sCharOK, Mid(s, j, 1)) = 0 Then
            rc.Interior.Color = vbYellow
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Next rc

End Sub
```

Comment: You could instead use Find & Replace, replacing with a specified format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this line in your If clause. However, it won't work if a space is found.

```
rc.Characters(j, 1).Font.Color = vbRed
```

Answer (score 0):

Just after or before painting the background yellow, you can do this:

```
rc.Characters(j, 1).Font.Bold = True
```

You can change font type, color, size, make it italic or bold. I think Excel doesn't allow one to chance the filling of part of a cell, but if you change the cell's background color to yellow and make the characters bold in a bigger font, your user will be able to spot the difference.